# SharePoint 2013 User Profile Sync exclusion filters

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, user-profile-service

I'm trying to figure out if there is anyway to create an exclusion filter for importing expired only profiles from Active Directory through the synchronization connection for user profiles.

The accountExpires attribute will remove all profiles that has been set to expire if the operator is set to Is present. Regardless if this date has passed or not. I just want to stop importing and have SharePoint remove user profiles that expiration date has passed.

Answer (score 1):

To Exclude all accounts which are either disabled, locked out, or their password has expired try:

userAccountControl Bit on equals 2 OR 
userAccountControl Bit on equals 5 OR 
userAccountControl Bit on equals 24 OR

Here is a handy reference table
[image]

Regards,
Bismarck

Answer (score 0):

this is what we have, we just importing only active users

```
   userAccountControl   Bit on equals   2
```

This will only import active accounts in AD.

Comment: Correct this will remove accounts that have been set to be disabled in active directory. Accounts that have been expired will still be imported in. I'm trying to see if I can configure an exclusion filter to remove only the accounts that have expired prior to today.

Comment: tryt his LDAP query http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a3156ae6-3362-48e4-a872-286a624e0b1c/ldap-account-expiration-query?forum=winservergen

Answer (score -1):

Try to use "userAccountControl Bit on equals 24" then.